# apache 2 virtual host ssl configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, configuration

Why is it that some of the directives in ssl configuration are placed withing a virtual host section? if one decides to just support one website in a server, couldn't all SSL configuration just be placed in the global server context?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you want every port that Apache listens on to be running SSL, then `SSLEngine On`, etc. in the server context makes sense.

For the most part, people want to have a non-encrypted listener (if only to redirect to the encrypted one), so most example you see take that into account and place the config in the virtual host context.